# Display Bootstrap Modal if the condition is true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I want to display the bootstrap modal on button click in ASp.net MVC if the condition is true or false.
Say eg if I check the login credentials and if it fails then how to display the error in a bootstrap modal or bootstrap alerts.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link href="~/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

     <script>
         $(function()
         {
             $("#mybutton").click(function(){
                 var test1 = $('#test').val();
                 if(test1 == "Value")
                     $("#myModal").modal('show');
             });
         });
     </script>

</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test" placeholder="Enter A Value" />
        <button type="submit" value="Click" name="click" id="mybutton">Click Me!</button>            


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How it can be achieved???

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Please update question with some valid code and what you have tried.

Comment: Hi @BonMacalindong

Updated the question please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code its working fine . i am created link in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1543/

```
  <script>
$(function()
{
  $("#mybutton").click(function(){
  var mycodition=true;
  if(mycodition)
   $("#myModal").modal('show');
     return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: plus 1 for adding the jsFiddle link.

Comment: Thanks @AmeteBlessed :-)

Comment: Yes @MayankBhuvnesh

Comment: Nothing i think you check it again @MayankBhuvnesh

Comment: @Surajghosi Thanks for the reply.
I tried this, but the modal is not displayed.

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh Still facing issue. i have check jsFiddle link and its working perfect.

Comment: @Surajghosi In jsFiddle it's running, I have checked that too......
But while creating MVC application it's not showing the modal

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh you have to return false other wise  post back occure

Comment: @Surajghosi I tried the same on button onClick event but got nothing...

Comment: send me your code on my email id surajkumarghosi@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening the popup from script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopup() {
        if(condition){
        $("#YourModalId").modal('show');
       }
    }
</script>
```